# VBA sorting Excel rows in ascending order but excluding first row?

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, excel-2007

I was using the below code successfully to, once I populate a worksheet with data, sort the data in ascending order based on the `B` column, the first row being record headers; `B` column being the `REPTNO` column.

For sample data I had B1 containing `REPTNO` and B2-B17 containing `SR0238-SR0253`. Everything was good, but then when I cleared out B2-B17 and submitted to user for testing, something strange happened.

My user entered a record into row 2 with the value of `JF0007` for `REPTNO`. When my below code processes, my first and second row are flipping (J coming before R), causing my "Header" column to be on the second row instead of remaining on the first.

What do I need to change to sort only the second row onward, excluding the first row? My row 1 needs to remain as row 1 for when I output to a .txt file.

The value of `rowCnt` in this situation is 2 (The header row + the 1 data row that is entered.

**EDIT2:**

```
    ' Sort by REPTNO field
    Dim xlSort As XlSortOrder
    xlSort = xlAscending

    If rowCnt > 2 Then
        With Worksheets("Export")

            .range("B2:B" & rowCnt).Sort Key1:=.range("B2"), Order1:=xlSort, Header:=xlNo, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        End With
    End If
```

It appears to only be swapping the first row (Header row) when there is 1 record entered (row 2). When I inputted a second data record into row 3 `REPTNO = JF0005`, the `REPTNO` value remained as B1. It does however appear this code is not functioning as I thought it was.

I need to sort all the rows (row 2 - however many rows there are) based on their `REPTNO` value. Sadly, my current code is ONLY ordering the data in the `REPTNO` column, or `B`.

Comment: `.range("B2:B" & rowCnt).Sort` only sorts column B. If you have other columns which need to be included then you will need to expand that range.  Eg:  `.range("A2:J" & rowCnt).Sort`

Comment: You're telling us that your data has a header row but in the call to `Sort` you have `Header:=xlNo` - try `Header:=xlYes`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the sorting glitches up a little when there isn't anything to sort, since obviously when there's only one cell, it doesn't have anything to sort and might as well just be skipped.

So I'd just recommend checking that there's more than one row filled in first, and skip the sorting if there isn't.

```
' Sort by REPTNO field
Dim xlSort As XlSortOrder
xlSort = xlAscending

With Worksheets("Export")
    If .Range("B3") <> ""
        .range("B2:B" & rowCnt).Sort Key1:=.range("B2"), Order1:=xlSort, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End if
End With
```

Comment: I did something similar, checking the total number of rows for being greater than 2. However I did note that my code is only sorting the `REPTNO` or `B` column, not sorting the entire row. For instance when I had `JF0007` followed by `JF0005`, when sorted, `JF0005 ` appeared before `JF0007`, but the two only switched places in their column. Where `JF0005` ended up was with data that was entered with `JF0007`. I'm needing all data associated with the sorted column value to move with the value into it's new sort order.

Comment: Thanks for the help mattboy! Tim got me straightened out. Need to expand the range of my .Sort